# Is there a component that increases current?

Tags: resistors

There is a component that increases resistance and therefore reduces current, the resistor. I was wondering if there is a component I can use to increase current in a circuit.

Comment: A resistor increases nothing. This is a dipole component with a constant V/I ratio, called the resistance, and which transforms into heat the supplied power P=V*I=R*I²=V²/R.

Comment: There are some devices (particular diodes, gas discharge tubes, florescent light tubes) that exhibit *localized* "negative impedance" where, at certain voltages/currents, an increase in current causes a decrease in voltage across the component. Your question, however, is unclear.

Comment: an extra battery?

Comment: As people have said, your question is unclear. Try to explain better your circuit and what you want to achieve.

Comment: The component you're looking for is simply a wire. Shorting the source with a wire normally allows you to get the maximum current out of it.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

resistors in parallel will do the job. less resistance and increasing the current.

Comment: How is that any different from simply using a smaller resistor? Also, in a circuit where there currently isn't a resistor, adding more resistors won't increase the current...